# O que é o "Bun"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, runtime, deno, bun

Hoje me deparei com uma novidade em uma rede social, mencionando o [Bun](https://bun.sh/),  descrito como:

> O mais novo e performático *runtime* JavaScript...

Comumente eu vejo essa imagem sendo compartilhada e demonstrando a "performance absurda" desse *runtime* [bun](/questions/tagged/bun):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Creio que muitos já tenham conhecimento que performance não é o único critério levado em consideração para se escolher qual linguagem usar para alguns tipos de projetos.

O Bun, pelo que entendi, vem se demonstrando uma alternativa ao [deno](/questions/tagged/deno) e ao já experiente de guerra [node](/questions/tagged/node) e pelo pouco que sei, ele meio que se baseou em algumas coisas do [deno](/questions/tagged/deno) como
por exemplo suporte nativo ao TypeScript. Ainda sim, eu pergunto:

- O que difere este novo *runtime* dos demais já existentes ([Deno](https://deno.land/) e [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/))?
- Ele tem algo que possa ser considerado revolucionário e que possa ser motivo de ocupar o lugar do Node.js?

---

<sup>O projeto teve sua versão [1.0 lançada em 08/09/2023](https://bun.sh/blog/bun-v1.0).</sup>

Comment: O tal Bun parece mesmo promissor, o melhor dele não é exatamente a velocidade, mas sim o suporte nativo a uma série de coisas, não chega a ser revolucionário, mas é o grande diferencial, como [respondi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/558802/3635). No entanto não dá para afirmar que em 5 ou 50 anos isso vai ser algo bom ou adotado pela comunidade, você pode notar como parte dos devs no mercado só seguem o que é dito como moda, não porque é bom.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Respondendo ao titulo, é um programa capaz de executar JavaScript, no entanto faz muito mais do que isso, como [transpilar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189894/3635) outras linguagens e uma série de ferramentas nativas. Basicamente um concorrente do [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/) e [Deno](https://deno.land/) que promete ser muito mais performático, como demonstrado na imagem que anexou a pergunta.

> O que difere este novo runtime dos demais já existentes (Deno e Node.js)?

O **suporte nativo** a uma série de recursos comuns hoje em dia, que dispensarão recursos extras/externos, sendo provavelmente a diferença mais relevante.

Algumas das diferenças *internas* do *Node.js* e *Deno* em comparação ao Bun, é que ao invés de usar o motor [V8](https://v8.dev/), o Bun usa o framework [JavaScriptCore](https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/tree/main/Source/JavaScriptCore) (também usado pelo motor Webkit). Ele é escrito em boa parte em [Zig](https://ziglang.org/) (como pode observar no [repositório](https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/tree/main/src)), com algumas partes variando entre [c](/questions/tagged/c) ou [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

Não é possível enumerar todas compatibilidades e incompatibilidades dos 3 em uma única resposta, ficaria uma resposta extremamente longa, e mesmo que tentasse enumerar é provável que algo ficaria faltando, mas no site oficial temos uma página dedicada a mostrar a compatibilidade do *Bun* com o *Node.js*:

- https://bun.sh/docs/runtime/nodejs-apis#node_compressionstream

Sendo um projeto **beta** (atualmente na versão [0.1.3 em 12/07/2022](https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/releases)) isso faria a resposta se tornar *desatualizada* e incorreta em meses, é melhor aguardamos para afirmar qualquer coisa, principalmente uma melhora na documentação do *Bun*, que não me parece algo bom ainda. Recomendo por enquanto acompanhar o roadmap: https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/issues/159

> Ele tem algo que possa ser considerado revolucionário e que possa ser motivo de ocupar o lugar do Node.js?

Como disse antes, o **suporte nativo** a uma série de recursos comuns hoje em dia, e é o que difere ele dos demais. Não chega a ser revolucionário, mas é o fator que com certeza é o que torna o projeto promissor.

Recursos nativos:

- Gerenciador de pacote compatível com [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/) (o que não garante que qualquer pacotes irá funcionar corretamente)
- Variáveis env carregam automaticamente, usando `process.env` e `Bun.env` (dispensando o *dotenv*)
- Transpilador Typescript e JSX
- Algumas bibliotecas (ou muitas) comuns em outros lugares, como `fetch()`, `WebSocket` e [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)
- Executor de tarefas para scripts via `package.json`
- [`"paths"` no `tsconfig.json`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) é suportado nativamente, juntamente com `exports` em `package.json`
- Ferramenta semelhante ao WebPack

Os *loaders* irão resultar em:

| Entrada | Loader | Saída |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `.js` | JSX + JavaScript | `.js` |
| `.jsx` | JSX + JavaScript | `.js` |
| `.ts` | TypeScript + JavaScript | `.js` |
| `.tsx` | TypeScript + JSX + JavaScript | `.js` |
| `.mjs` | JavaScript | `.js` |
| `.cjs` | JavaScript | `.js` |
| `.mts` | TypeScript | `.js` |
| `.cts` | TypeScript | `.js` |
| `.toml` | TOML | `.js` |
| `.css` | CSS | `.css` |
| `.*` | file | string |

O `.env` não resulta em saída e o outros formatos resultam em `file`. Note que `file` substitui a importação por um `URL` (ou um caminho).

> Até o momento as APIs [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html), [`path`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html), e [`process`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html) do Node.js estão apenas parcialmente implementadas, então pode ser que alguns pacotes [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/) ou códigos existentes não irão funcionar corretamente.

Eu poderia citar uma série de coisas especificas, com exemplos, mas isso seria levar a pergunta a situações opinativas ou muito longas, e é muito cedo para falar qualquer coisa sobre isso (recomendo [formular perguntas especificas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=bun,javascript) se surgir alguma dúvida sobre recursos específicos).

Em resumo é isso que é o melhor do *Bun*, **suporte nativo** a muitas coisas que é comuns em frameworks e ferramentas usadas hoje em dia. Chega a ser revolucionário? Não considero, mas considero ainda sim como ótimo.

> **Nota:** não relacionado diretamente ao *Bun*, *Node.js* ou *Deno*, mas se formos falar de algo revolucionário no mundo JavaScript, independente do motor, me parece que até agora é o [*WebAssembly*](https://webassembly.org/).

Comment: Uma coisa que eu achei interessante, é que ele não usa o V8 como o Node ou Deno fazem. Ele tem um interpretador escrito na linguagem `Zig`, o que pra mim suou esquisito de cara, pois nunca tinha ouvido falar. Nem sabia que existia algo aqui no SOpt, mas vou dar uma pesquisada melhor e tentar entender o que essa linguagem tem de tao especial pra ter sido escolhida no lugar de C ou Rust...

Comment: @CmteCardeal eles usam o JavaScriptCore no lugar do V8, o Zig é a linguagem que escolheram para escrever. JavaScriptCore é o motor/framework usado no Webkit: https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/tree/main/Source/JavaScriptCore. Exemplo de navegador que o usa o Webkit é o Safari.

Comment: Boa, isso explica melhor. Achei que tinha sido escolha do criador do bun.

Comment: @CmteCardeal em boa parte é escrito em Zig, mas tem partes escritos em C e C++ (detalhes: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlVDz.png). Provavelmente escolheram o Zig para facilitar escrever e ao mesmo tempo por uma performance boa (não fiz um benchmark para saber de fato os detalhes, é o segundo projeto que vejo usando Zig).